# How to make a spacy matcher pattern using verb tense and form

Tags: python, spacy

I am starting with nlp in spaCy. I am using the [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) with a Spanish model and I would like to know if it is possible to create a pattern that allows to find the form of the verb and the Tense at the same time

In the spanish model the TAG attributes are something like:

`AUX__Mood=Sub|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=End`

I need a pattern to match `Tense=Pres` and `VerbForm=Fin`

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63708214/how-to-make-a-spacy-matcher-pattern-using-verb-tense-mood) I have tried to modify the regex:

```py
matcher.add("MOOD_SUB", [[{"TAG": {"REGEX": ".*Tense=Pres|VerbForm=End.*"}}]])
```

but I have not been able to obtain the expected results. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, this is a great question. Could you add an example of input and correct output for people who understand spaCy but not Spanish like myself?

Comment: For the record, the code from the question you link to seems to be able to select things with your regex, though I had to modify "End" to "Fin" to match the example sentence given there, since I'm not sure what the VerbForm values mean.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest in helping me. I studied some regex and was able to get the result I expected with the next line: 
`.*Tense=Past.*VerbForm=Fin"`

Comment: Oh. I guess maybe the pipe was an issue, but it looks like the main problem was you used `End` instead of `Fin` then...

Comment: Yeah, the pipe was the issue. But you are right is `VerbForm=Fin` not `VerbForm=End` When I translated and wrote the question it was misspelled